# json php return string null

Tags: php, json

I am following a very interesting tutorial which will help me a lot
But I'm in trouble.

My php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1");
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '123456';
$dbname = 'directory';
$sql = "select e.id, e.firstName, e.lastName, e.title, e.picture, count(r.id) reportCount " . 
    "from employee e left join employee r on r.managerId = e.id " .
    "group by e.id order by e.lastName, e.firstName";
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);  
    $employees = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $dbh = null;
    echo '{"items":'. json_encode($employees) .'}'; 
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
}
?>
```

some are returning null string especially when they have accents.

I tried several alternatives like as

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

and

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $dbh)
```

Comment: i see you are using `FETCH_OBJ`, if you change that to `FETCH_ASSOC` will it still produce the same error?

Comment: The `mysql_query` doesn't make sense because you're using PDO. Try this instead with the PDO invocation: `$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));`

Comment: Which php version are you using?

Comment: @JeroenFlamman I use 5.4.25. The solution presented by Jonathan worked. Thank you for replie

Comment: OK, great that it is working. Since you run 5.4 `json_encode($employees, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` can keep your JSON readable if you like that.